# Consolibyte Quickbooks use of an unknown class

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, add-on, tax

I use quickbooks-php. If I want to get a Quickbooks tax rate (not in the online US account). I'm looking for error

```
QuickBooks_Loader::load(): Failed opening required '/var/www/project/addons/quickbooks/vendor/consolibyte/quickbooks/QuickBooks/IPP/Object/EffectiveTaxRate.php'
```

I use 3.2 version in  composer

```
"consolibyte/quickbooks": "3.2",
```

As I understand this file there are only in dev version. 
When I switch to the development version everything is fine.
In 3.3 version the same error. 
Waiting for reply. Thank you.

Code what i use

```
$service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_TaxCode();
return $service->query(self::getQB()->getContext(), self::getQB()->getRealm(), "SELECT * FROM TaxCode");
```

When I added it file (from dev version EffectiveTaxRate.php) to the vendor/consolibyte/quickbooks/QuickBooks/IPP/Object/,  all is well but it is not a solution to the problem, after the composer update the problem will come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noted the solution in your post:

> As I understand this file there are only in dev version. When I switch to the development version everything is fine.

Use the development version until a new release is made which contains the file you need.